# benefit of LinkedBlockingQueue in Executors.newFixedThreadPool

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I don't able to find out the benefit of why JDK used LinkedBlockingQueue over ArrayBlockingQueue in Executors.newFixedThreadPool.

```
return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                      0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                      new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

The benefit of ArrayBlockingQueue is that its fast but the collection should be bounded and defined in the beginning, which is all applicable in newFixedThreadPool.

So, there is some benefit or extra functionality needed which couldn't be achieved by ArrayBlockingQueue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fixedThreadPool does not mean that the internal queue is bounded but instead only a max number of threads can be created. From the Oracle documentation : `Tasks are submitted to the pool via an internal queue, which holds extra tasks whenever there are more active tasks than threads.` (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)

Which leads to the conclusion that if the queue is unbounded, then a LinkedBlockingQueue is more relevant since an ArrayBlockingQueue is bounded and its size cannot change.

Comment: in FixedThreadPool, the initial number of queue (first param) is exactly same as max number of thread (second param), and we give a bounded size which is mandatory param, so it can't be unbounded.

Comment: even for single thread, JDK has implemented it same way: new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                                    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()

Comment: are you talking about the maximumPoolSize ? from javadoc it is the `the maximum number of threads to allow in the  pool`. Nowhere is specified the size of the internal queue. Moreoever as you stated there is a `new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()`, which is actually bounded to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: I am talking about the initial pool size, which is same as maximum pool size. So, it will create maximumPoolSize in the first instance itself.

Comment: I really don't get your point and I think you are confused between pool size and queue size. The LinkedBlockingQueue is only used to store tasks that cannot be directly handled

Comment: So are you saying, if I call Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5), will it not create five thread instantly? If it will do so, then it will make 5 entry in queue too!

Comment: I am saying that the size of the threadpool and the LinkedBlockingQueue are two distinct things. Having a threadpool of 5 does not mean having a queue of 5. Having a threadpool of 5 means you are allocating 5 threads to do some computations. Then if the threadpool is 'overwhelmed' i.e. `there are more active tasks than threads` then the internal queue will grow ! More on the threadpools : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html